# SQL query syntaxt error near WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a very simple SQL query that, for some reason is not working. Could you take a look and tell what's wrong with it. Thanks!.

```
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM payments WHERE payments.num_operac= " . $txn_id;

$txnid_exists = mysql_query($sql);

error_log("Duplicate txn id check query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
```

Here's what I got

> [18-Apr-2014 12:24:14 UTC] Duplicate txn id check query
>   failed:
> Unknown column '0GF60424XU536804C' in 'where
>   clause'
> 1054

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM payments WHERE payments.num_operac= " . $txn_id;
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM payments WHERE payments.num_operac= '".$txn_id."'";
```

String data must be enclosed with single quote.

You are using deprecated `mysql_` functions and wide open for sql injection.

Start using `mysqli_` or `PDO` with prepared statement.

or at least

```
$txn_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txn_id']);
```

till you learn `mysqli_` or `PDO`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: Thanks! I've dug a little bit into PDO :) pretty useful and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

you need this:

It is telling you the SQL statement is incorrect and the problem is the `WHERE clause` of the statement.
you should my use the `single quote` like my query `''`

```
.....payments.num_operac= '".$txn_id."'";
```